# pre-image of a set that isn't in the image of that set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{X,Y,Z\}$ be a set.

Define a function $f:A \to \mathbb N$ as the set of ordered pairs 
$$f=\{(X,1),(Y,2),(Z,3)\}$$

then, the pre-image of $f$ under $C \subset \mathbb N$ can be defined as
$$f^{-1}[C]=\{x \in A: f(x) \in C\}$$

for example, $f^{-1}[\{1,2\}]=\{X,Y\}$.

Further, let $D$ be a set with $D \subset \mathbb N$ and $D \cap f(A) = \emptyset$

Then, is the following true?: $$f^{-1}[D] = \emptyset$$
for example, $f^{-1}[\{5,6\}]=\emptyset$. Or is does it just not make sense to talk about this pre-image? I guess my confusion arises from thinking about "arrows" from $A$ to $\mathbb R$; there is no "arrow" from $\emptyset$ to $D$.

Comment: yes, I corrected that, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant $D\cap f(A)=\emptyset$, then $f^{-1}(D)=\emptyset$.

Here's and example which may be helpful. You many have seen the relation $f(f^{-1}(A)\subseteq A$.  We don't have equality here, because $A$ may contain elements outside of $f(A)$.